# OKI C830 printer that is manually asking to press "Online" everytime we print a page

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have a OKI C830 printer that is manually asking to press "Online" everytime we print a page. I am thinking it is because it believes the paper tray is loaded with different size paper than required by the print out. Not sure how to fix this and I can't find anything on it googling.

Comment: Is it an A4 tray loaded with A4 paper, with the tab on the tray set appropriately? Anything in the manual feed tray? Is the manual feed door closed?

Comment: Tried these but it still is giving me issues. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Check settings for something similar to "verify identity for each document" or similar - I'd say this is a function aimed at a public printer, where you wish it to not print before you're AT the printer.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I figured out this must just be a hardware issue. I gotta called OKI and ask if there is a way to get the part fixed (the tray pins in the back) or buy a new printer, lol.